# How do i dymanically set range of date into jquery datepicker?

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have gotten the earliest date and latest date via

```
$query = "SELECT MIN(date_added) FROM books 
            UNION SELECT MIN(date_created) FROM news
            UNION SELECT MIN(date_created) FROM registered_member
            UNION SELECT MIN(date_of_rental) FROM rent
            UNION SELECT MIN(datetime) FROM shopping_cart";
```

this returns me the earliest and latest.

I was thinking how do i use the data return to put into the range of jquery datepicker?
This is my current code without any options added.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you properly you might use `minDate` and `maxDate` options like:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("option", "minDate", YourMinDate);
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("option", "maxDate", YourMaxDate);
```

Also you may use it in constructor:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: YourMinDate,
    maxDate: YourMaxDate
});
```

Comment: you may want to set the dateformat first with $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

Comment: the author may do this if needed

Comment: yup i needed this. THanks alot this works as what i wanted now!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.datepicker').datePicker({

            startDate: '<?php echo $mindate; ?>', // MM/DD/YYYY format
            endDate: '<?php echo $maxdate; ?>' // MM/DD/YYYY
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the plugin you can just supply the min and max as options

```
var myMinDate = ...;
var myMaxDate = ...;
$("#datepicker").datepicker({minDate: myMinDate, maxDate: myMaxDate});
```

See the datepicker documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max) for more info